# vscode terminal is not accepting control characters

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been happily using vscode's terminal with its bash keystrokes.

However suddenly the control characters are not getting interpreted. They are being printed:

[image]

Any thoughts on what I've broken in the terminal?  It was working fine yesterday.  I've tried quitting and restarting, but no dice.

Comment: If you look at the right side of the terminal window, does it show that you're still using a bash shell? I've accidentally changed the terminal type being launched before, so maybe it's something like that

Comment: It shows zsh shell

Comment: Hmm...zsh uses keys in iTerm but it seems not in vscode.